# How to align geom_text according to clock values

Tags: r, ggplot2, text-alignment, geom-text

Hopefully someone can help me with this problem. I´ve tried several solutions with no success.

I want to replicate following figure #1. Therefor I´ve added the variable clock (with values from 1 to 12) to my data frame to use it as parameter for the alignment of geom_text.

*Figure I want to replicate:*

[image: figure i want to replicate]

*My figure:*

[image: my figure]

Following my code for plotting:

```
p1 <- ggplot(data, aes(x=tax, y=employment)) + geom_point(colour = ifelse(style == 1 | style == 2,"black","grey")) + geom_smooth(method=lm, se=FALSE)
p1 + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 0.8), ylim = c(0.5,0.9), expand = FALSE) + labs(x = "1 - participation taxrate", y="Employment rate") + geom_text(aes(family = "Times New Roman", label=ifelse(style == 1 | style == 2 ,Country,''))) + theme_bw()
```

Comment: would you be happy with more legible labels (ie less/no overlap) or do you want to remake your example figure exactly?

Comment: @NathanDay if it's possible i would like to position the text according to my clock variable. Otherwise I'll try to make it more legible with ggrepel. Or do you have a easier solution?

Comment: you can use `position = position_nudge()` with appropriate values for x and y.

Comment: i would fall back to `ggrepel` myself. Looks like @shadow might might be onto something, I was going to try the same idea with hjust and vjust

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have specified the clock value, you can easily calculate the direction and therefore the amount you want to nudge in each direction:

```
angle <- clock/12*2*pi
radius <- 0.01
ng <- data.frame(x = radius * sin(angle), 
                 y = radius * cos(angle))
```

Then you can just add `position = position_nudge(x = ng$x, y = ng$y)` to the `geom_text` statement. Below I have also removed the grid lines that don't appear in the figure you are trying to replicate.

```
p1 + coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 0.8), ylim = c(0.5,0.9), expand = FALSE) + 
  labs(x = "1 - participation taxrate", y="Employment rate") + 
  geom_text(aes(family = "Times New Roman", label=ifelse(style == 1 | style == 2 ,Country,'')), 
            position = position_nudge(x = ng$x, y = ng$y)) + 
  theme_bw() +
  theme(panel.grid.major.x = element_blank(), 
        panel.grid.minor.x = element_blank())
```